# find does not work, locate does

Tags: bash, arch-linux, find, manjaro, locate

So I have this bit:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep --ignore-case networkmanager | grep --ignore-case service | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=" "
```

Which gives as output:

```
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
NetworkManager-wait-online.service
NetworkManager.service
```

And I have this bit:

```
find / -name NetworkManager-dispatcher.service 2>/dev/null
```

with the following output:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

**However,**

```
find / -name $(systemctl list-unit-files | grep --ignore-case networkmanager | grep --ignore-case service | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=" ") -print 2>/dev/null
```

gives nothing whereas:

```
locate $(systemctl list-unit-files | grep --ignore-case networkmanager | grep --ignore-case service | cut --fields=1 --delimiter=" ")
```

shows:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service
/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d/NetworkManager-ovs.conf
```

*Why oh why doesn't* `find` *find anything???*  **;-)**

<sub>Before you ask *"Why don't you use locate then?"*, the answer to that is: I'm on Manjaro and `locate` is not standard whereas `find` is...</sub>

Comment: You might be interested in exploring systemctl usage: `systemctl -t service -p FragmentPath show 'Network*'` or `systemctl -t service cat 'Network*'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why oh why doesn't `find` find anything???

Drop `2>/dev/null` and see the error. It will be:

```
find: paths must precede expression: NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

`-name` needs exactly one argument, you're providing three. The first one is accepted. The second one is not recognized as a valid part of an expression, so `find` assumes it's a path, (like `/` you provided); but "paths must precede expression".

The invocation is syntactically wrong and it simply *fails* rather than "doesn't find anything".

On the other hand `locate` can take more than one pattern easily. This doesn't mean it's flawless. Unquoted `$()` is [often wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Here you want the output to be split, still other issues may occur.

Comment: Urgh!  **I'm an idiot!**  *I should have thought about dropping the `2> /dev/null` myself!!!*  Dziękuję!